# splitSeries error with packedbubble in Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to use the packedbubble from HighCharts in Angular

ng version give me this: 
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 15.2.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

In my component.ts I added the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts';

require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(HighCharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
    readonly menuComponent: MenuComponent,
    readonly globals: Globals,
    private service: ConsultaSercService
  ) {
    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(
      // Create 100 users
      Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, k) => createNewUser(k + 1))
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bubbleChartActive();
  }

  bubbleChartActive(){
    HighCharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'packedbubble',
          height: '100%'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Carbon emissions around the world (2014)'
      },
      tooltip: {
          useHTML: true,
          pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}m CO<sub>2</sub>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
      packedbubble: {
          minSize: '20%',
          maxSize: '100%',
          zMin: 0,
          zMax: 1000,
          layoutAlgorithm: {
              gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
              splitSeries: true,
              seriesInteraction: false,
              dragBetweenSeries: true,
              parentNodeLimit: true
          },
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '{point.name}',
              style: {
                  color: 'black',
                  textOutline: 'none',
                  fontWeight: 'normal'
              }
          }
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        type:'packedbubble',
        name: 'Network',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Domain1',
            value: 4
          },
          {
            name: 'Domain2',
            value: 450
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    });
  }
}
```

But typescript in Atom says: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string.

In the line of the key splitSeries of layoutAlgorithm

In the package.json I have: "highcharts": "^8.2.2"

in the html I have:

```
<div>
  <div id="container" style="width:100%; height: 400px; display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

The console from Chrome doesn't show errors

**Finally when I run ng serve

The HTML doesn't show anything**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some types are missing. Try to extend the packed bubble options interface.

```
interface ExtendedChart extends Highcharts.PlotPackedbubbleOptions {
  layoutAlgorithm: {
    splitSeries: any;
  };
}
```

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-packedbubble

Comment: Thank you, that works fine! But I had another issue with that, I don't know how can I structure the series variable from array, because I have an array but just the series variable takes the father

Comment: Please create a separate topic for that issue ;)